Как найти в тексте 16-ричные коды символов и заменить их на сами символы?
Есть функция, которая заменяет эмодзи в тексте на hex-последовательности.
function convertEmoji(string $text, ?string $encoding = 'UTF-8'): string
{
    $emoTypes = [
        '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u', // Match Emoticons
        '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u', // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
        '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u',// Match Transport And Map Symbols
        '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u', // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
        '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u', // Match Dingbats
    ];
        
    $clean_text = "";
    foreach ($emoTypes as $pattern)
    {
        $clean_text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($encoding) {
            return '\x'.base_convert(mb_ord($matches[0], $encoding), 10, 16);
        }, empty($clean_text) ? $text : $clean_text);
    }
        
    return $clean_text;
}
$converted = convertEmoji("Hello  люди");
var_dump($converted);//string(36) "Hello \x1f600\x1f4e7\x1f600 люди"
//var_dump(goBack($converted)); // "Hello  люди"

Как теперь при выводе этого текста раскодировать их обратно, например из \x1F600 в ? Какое должно быть регулярное выражение для поиска и замены, может выгоднее сделать через форматирование строки sprintf?

Из-за того, что вы не заменили \ на \\, сделать однозначное обратное преобразование теперь невозможно

Да и из-за того, что длина кода является непостоянной, сделать обратное преобразование теперь тоже невозможно, так как непонятно, в каком месте код заканчивается

@andreymal Да, комментарий оказался полезным. Подскажите, какой тогда формат преобразования для вставки будет возможно вернуть обратно и проверить по промежуткам из вопроса? Например так \\x1f600\? Текст, который вставляется в БД, я могу обрабатывать, чего нельзя сказать об ограничении на модификацию таблиц...

Для непонятливых ещё раз поясняем: НИКАКИЕ ТАБЛИЦЫ МЕНЯТЬ НЕ НАДО. На них и так уже стоит правильная кодировка. Надо всего лишь выставить кодировку соединения. О чем и говорит конкретно эта ошибка. И на будущее врать в своих вопросах не следует.

@Ипатьев Если мы недопоняли друг друга, то надо уточнить причину недопонимания, например в комментариях. Особенно когда решается закрывать вопрос как дубликат или нет, без его прочтения до конца и предварительной смены на совершенно иной. :)
Подскажите, где в изначальном вопросе я написал то, что было интерпретировано Вами, как обман, дабы я более детально мог в последствии описывать проблемный момент без недопониманий?

Вы врали про то, что данные уже в БД и без функции раскодирования никак не обойтись (хотя и это было шито белыми нитками - так не бывает, чтобы данные записали сто лет назад и забыли, а сейчас вдруг понадобилось прочитать. Их читают сразу же, то есть речь о текущей разработке). А сейчас уже "летают, но низенько-низенько" - оказывается, можно все переиграть и закодировать по-новому. То есть снова городить костыли там, где ничто не мешает ходить ногами. Кроме спеси "Ах мой вопрос закрыли!".

@Ипатьев так в этом и есть суть недопонимания. Давайте обсудим:

Данные в БД вставлены в том виде, в котором я подготовил строку для вставки
Действительно, этот вопрос возник во время "текущей разработки" и первое возникшее решение, для меня - это выполнить обратную замену по регулярному выражению, о чём и был вопрос
Подтверждаю, что можно пойти иным путём и задать кодировку соединения с БД, но это уже решение, которое не совсем по теме регулярных выражений


А в итоге из-за вашей спеси и эгоизма, "я хочу пользоваться костылем!", все другие люди с такой же проблемой тоже получат в качестве ответа костыль, а не нормальное решение. Мне пришлось хотя бы убрать из вопроса любые упоминания о БД, чтобы гугл не приводил сюда людей по тексту ошибки за костыльным решением пятнадцатилетней давности.

@Ипатьев Ну, хорошо, для конкретной задачи решение с регулярными выражениями может быть избыточным и костыльным. Однако, я не до конца согласен с тем, что поиск строки в виде диапазона из hex-последовательности и её замена на 1 символ, который эта последовательность представляет, является уж слишком бессмысленной задачей. Как из диапазона этих значений для поиска символа /[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u -> сделать регулярное для поиска строки \x1F64F. Если, вы согласны, то теперь я могу немного иначе переформулировать основной вопрос

Если вы хотите снова завести шарманку про вставку в mysql, то этого не стоит делать. С БД надо работать по-человечески. А для раскодирования этого мусора текущей формулировки вопроса вполне достаточно (тем более, что "полезный" комментарий andreymal - это типичное невежество, которое так любят демонстрировать местные доброхоты), редактирование не требуется. Чтобы решить свою вселенскую проблему, возьмите регулярку отсюда stackoverflow.com/a/2934602 и внутри вызывайте функции, которыми кодировали,  в обратном порядке

@Ипатьев А вот именно этот ответ я и искал. Благодарю. Нет, не про вставку, а про по-сути копию вопроса из вашего комментария

@Ипатьев раз уж вы сами призвали меня в этот вопрос — ну давайте покажите мне, как вы собираетесь кодировать строку вида \x1f4a9\\x1f4a9 и декодировать её обратно без потерь

Ну ок, "однозначное" преобразование сделать нельзя. Хотя однозначное никто и не просил. И с длиной, кстати, всё равно пальцем в небо

@Ипатьев ну давайте покажите мне, как вы собираетесь кодировать и декодировать строку вида 1✀1 если не хардкодить в регулярке конкретную длину или циферки 1 или 2 после \x

@Ипатьев ну и можно отметить, что по вашей ссылке «возьмите регулярку отсюда» в регулярке используется захардкоженная длина 4, да
